# larger video url is not loading inside react player

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, amazon-web-services, next.js

Hey all I am using react player to running the video inside my application. But the problem is when I use larger size video that is of more than one minutes then react player showing black interface.

you can see the image below.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hf3Ka.png

No control is working properly.

I am using following code for this operation.

```
<ReactPlayer
  // Disable download button
  config={{ file: { attributes: { controlsList: 'nodownload' } } }}

  // Disable right click
  onContextMenu={e => e.preventDefault()}

  // Your props
  url="https://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer_hd.mp4"
  className="react-player"
  controls
  width="100%"
  height="100%"
/>
```

Please someone help me. Thank you in advance.

Comment: The beginning of the video is all black.  Is it just that the video never started?  Without a reproducible example it's hard to tell.

Comment: @stdunbar Actually very small size video is started, like video of  10 second.